# wordpress rest api acting like no data is sent

Tags: wordpress, api, curl

I am trying to create a post with the wordpress rest api. With curl and postman I get the following response.

```
{"code":"empty_content","message":"Content, title, and excerpt are empty.","data":{"status":400}}
```

My curl command is

```
curl -X POST --user admin:secret http://mysite.local/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/ -d '{"post_title":"My New Title","Content":"the stuff","excerpt":"something"}'
```

I know I must be missing something basic here.  It acts like no post data is reaching it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by add the following option

`-H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Comment: It's silly that SO doesn't like it when we comment to say.... OMG THANK YOU!!!